# Plot freezes with arbitrary precision complex evaluations

Tags: plotting, bugs, complex, arbitrary-precision

I find that `Plot` has some strange behavior.

```
a = {{-5.355`3 I, 0.1589`3 }, {2.305`3, 0.01425`3}};
Det[a] // Abs
```

gives `0.374`

However,

```
f[x_] := Module[{},Det[a]];
Plot[f[3], {t, 0, 10}]
```

freezes. I'm not sure what `Plot` is doing with `Det[a]`.

By removing the `I` in `a` to make it all real, `Plot` does not freeze.

By removing the `3` in `a` to make it machine precision, `Plot` does not freeze.

It looks like only arbitratry precision complex will freeze `Plot`.
Can others reproduce this on their machine, or is it just something wrong with mine?

As mentioned in your replies, using `Evaluate` in `Plot` will help. But in fact, my code is some kind of short version of a long piece of code for numerical calculation where **using `Evaluate` in `Plot` is not possible**.

So I was tring to figure out what is happening behind the freeze. I tried adding `MaxRecursion->0` and `PlotPoints->2` so that there won't be thousands of times of evaluations. But it still freezes.

Comment: I'm guessing that it is spending all that time finding `Det[a]` thousands of times, once for each possible value of `t`. If you change it to `Plot[Evaluate[Det[a]],{t,0,3}]` then it quickly returns an empty plot because it only needs to evaluate the `Det` once and there are no real points to plot and `Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[Det[a]]],{t,0,3}]` quickly returns the plot with the real curve and the imaginary curve.

Comment: I tried adding `MaxRecursion -> 0` and `PlotPoints -> 2` so that there won't be  thousands of times of evaluations. But it still freezes.

Comment: @Bill, I think there is actually something more seriously wrong (and weird) going on ... For example, using `f[x_] := Module[{}, Print[x]; Det[a]; Abort[];];`, you can see that there is only one call to the `f`, which then gets stuck at calculating the determinant.

Comment: I would say this is some sort of bug when calling certain numerical linear algebra algorithm for arbitrary precision (likely the Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting). For example, the kernel also hangs if you use `Inverse`, `LUDecomposition` or `LinearSolve`, but it works for `QRDecomposition`, `PseudoInverse`, `Eigenvalues` ...

Comment: It's a plotting bug, which i will (dutifully) report.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, is it also possible to get some kind of an explanation for this behaviour? :) Do `*Plot` functions create some special "context" in which a function behaves differently than when called outside of them?

Comment: `Plot` uses some tactics to make exponent sizes relatively tame. These are not playing nice with initializations required by bignum linear algebra. Here is distilled version of that hang (wherein I do not try to explain internal context veriables): `Block[{Internal`$MinExponent = 2*Log10[$MinMachineNumber],
  Internal`$MaxExponent = 2*Log10[$MaxMachineNumber]}, 
 Det[{{-5.355`3 I, 0.1589`3 }, {2.305`3, 0.01425`3}}]]`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
a = {{-5.355`3 I, 0.1589`3}, {2.305`3, 0.01425`3}};
Det[a] // Abs

f[x_] := Module[{}, Det[a]];

Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[f[3]]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: I understand how this Evaluate helps, but I was tring to figure out what is happening behind the freeze. I tried adding `MaxRecursion -> 0` and `PlotPoints -> 2` so that there won't be  thousands of times of evaluations. But it still freezes. In fact, my code is some kind of short version of a long piece of code for numerical calculation where using Evaluate in Plot is not possible.